# Using 3 commands at the same time,(Logging snort packets,Remove the permission,Covert to txt by tcpdump), syntax error.

Tags: terminal, command, tcpdump, snort

I want to use three commands at the same time in the terminal, which are:

Logging snort packets :

```
$  snort -l /home/hduser/snort-logs
```

Remove the permission:

```
$  chmod a+rwx /home/hduser/snort-logs/snort.log.1490308103
```

Covert the captured packets from pcap to txt :

```
$  tcpdump -n -tttt -r /home/hduser/snort-logs/snort.log.1490308103 > /home/hduser/snort-logs/3.txt
```

They all work fine separately.Then I tried this to use them together :

```
$ snort -l /home/hduser/snort-logs && chmod a+rwx /home/hduser/snort-logs/snort.log.* && tcpdump -n -tttt -r /home/hduser/snort-logs/snort.log.* > /home/hduser/snort-logs/33.txt
```

It gave me :

```
tcpdump: syntax error
```

Also I tried & , ; , | , but all give the same syntax error.

Any suggestion to make it work ?